# Should a Go web application include all pages in one template?

Tags: performance, templates, go

Assume a web application has 100 pages/templates a header template footer template, and 10 or so other helper templates. Is it better to smash them all together and parse them as one into a single giant template object and pass it to every http handler. Or is it better to parse the 100 pages as individual template/objects. One for each http handler.

I am primarily interested from the perspective of performance. But any other advise regarding this question is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Since any template must be "executed" to produce the result, the question boils down to "will the pattern of requests from the front-end make it possible for the different templates to be executed concurrently (and then their results assembled)".

If the answer is "yes", then you might get the speedup, if "no", I'd say the speedup will be unlikely.

Also note that whether the front-end would make it possible to perform several such requests in parallel is also a open question as it heavily depends on how the requests are made: say, if the requsts are made via a single HTTP 1.1 connection, they will be serialized (the Nth request will have to wait until the response is received for the N-1th request); if you're requesting stuff via a websocket, you might implement pipelining.

Another thing to ponder is that if you were actually asking about executing these multiple templates when serving a *single* request, it all boils down to whether the concurrency of rendering will trump the time spent on synchronising the goroutines executing different templates.
Basically it's the same tradeoff as in the above case — just localised to the server's process.

---

In either case the proper answer to this sort of questions is "benchmark both solutions".
The latter case is the most trivial to benchmark as you'd need nothing besides the `testing` package.
The former is harder to evaluate as it'd require performing several trials while looking at the page loading stats in the developer tools window.

---

And last but not least is considering that while you might get noticeable speedup while executing multiple templates in parallel for a series of *sequential* requests hitting a multicore server, things might get different when several such requests come in parallel: that's simply because if rendering the templates for a single request would keep N CPU cores busy, doing the same for 100 concurrent requests would make the rendering goroutines compete for the cores.

That is, you'd need to perform realistic load testing, and this is a completely another story…